# getrowdata from nested (child datatable) datatables

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-1.2

```
    <h:dataTable width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" 
        value="#{managedBean.parentViewList}"
        binding="#{managedBean.parentDataTable}"
        var="parent">
        <h:column>
            <h:dataTable width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" 
                    binding="#{managedBean.childDataTable}"
                    value="#{parent.childViewList"}"
                    var="child">
                   <h:column>#{child.value1"}<h:column> 
                   <h:column>
                      <h:selectOneMenu id ="histActionsId"  
                       value="#{child.actionClicked}" 
                       onchange="return clickOnMyLink(this, id);">
                           <f:selectItems value="#{child.applicableActionList}"/>
                     </h:selectOneMenu>
                   <h:column>   
            </h:dataTable>
       </h:column>
     </h:dataTable>
```

Above is the nested data table and child table is having select dropdown. onchange of drop down clicking on some link which will call doSomething() method in managed bean.

How do I get the child object/index in the doSomething() method of managed bean? (jsf 1.x)

Comment: In managed bean i'm getting -1 as rowIndex value for both parentDataTable and childDataTable in doSomething() method.

Comment: In my eyes, it is not really clear what do you want to achive. Based on your posted code, are you sure that the javascript variable 'id' has a value?